# bundler: command not found: clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, clockwork

I want to use clockwork in my ruby on rails project.
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.0.9

i ran bundle install in root

```
Installing clockwork (0.7.5)
....
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

$ bundle show clockwork
/scratch/install/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.7.5
$ bundle exec clockwork config/clock.rb
The source :gemcutter is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
bundler: command not found: clockwork
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

I have no idea of how to call clockwork gem. It always gives me "command not found: clockwork". Other gems are all okay except this clockwork gem :(

Actually, i have the same problem as https://meta.discourse.org/t/how-to-run-clockwork-in-background/6176/4

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: No i'm not using RVM.

Comment: Is there a `clockwork` file in `...ruby193/bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need add [Daemons](https://github.com/ghazel/daemons) in your 'Gemfile'.

```
gem 'daemons'
```

Then run `bundle` to install Daemons gem. After you can run:

```
clockworkd -c YOUR_FILE.rb status
clockworkd -c YOUR_FILE.rb start
clockworkd -c YOUR_FILE.rb stop
```

Or:

```
bundle exec clockworkd -c YOUR_FILE.rb status
bundle exec clockworkd -c YOUR_FILE.rb start
bundle exec clockworkd -c YOUR_FILE.rb stop
```

Comment: I have tried this with `bundle install --deployment --binstubs` but I don't get the `clockworkd` command in my `app/bin` directory. Is there some additional magic that's needed?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran clockwork first time like this:

```
clockwork app/clock.rb
```

I got:

```
clockwork: command not found
```

Then I ran clockwork like this:

```
bundle exec clockwork app/clock.rb
```

And it worked, even when I uninstalled `daemons` gem and even when the later runs were without `bundle exec`